# Caps Lock pop up (Num Lock, Scroll Lock as well) on Windows 7 doesnt show any more?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, notifications

My pop up for when pressing Caps Lock on a Windows 7 x64 suddenly disapperead when starting the comp this morning?

Cant see any logical reasons, since I didn't tweak anything with the keyboard.

Suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 does not provide out-of-the-box a popup when pressing the Caps Lock key (or NumLock).

This function is usually provided by either the keyboard driver, the tools installed with the keyboard (Logitech SetPoint for instance) or a third-party utility (like [Clever Keyboard Indicator](http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/winind/winind.asp)).

If you installed an update to one of these programs or to the driver, you might have to reactivate the setting to show the popup.